# Is there any way to Convert pdf to png with custom settings? I'm using Android hopefully I can use termux

Tags: png, termux, pdf-conversion

I want to convert few pages of pdf with custom pixel density, height, width and, render pages with alpha channel and transparent background. How can I do that? Which software pkg and example of a command line that I can use
P.S: I also want to keep height and width unchanged for some pdfs.